# SQL - How do I make an auto computing column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, auto-update, heidisql

I've created a table named `House`, which has the column `'area'`.
I have another table named `HouseFire`, with the columns `'%_Burnt'` and `'area_burnt'`.
I have values for both `'area'` and `'%_Burnt'`. I want to make `'area_burnt'` to automatically give me the value as soon as I input the % value in '%_burnt'.
I'm using heidisql

Comment: You probably need a VIEW: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I doubt that it's even possible to create an [auto computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql) based on a field from another table.

Comment: This seems to be a UI problem, not a database problem.  Adjust the tags accordingly.